# Can't upload a file to sharepoint site's file directory using CSOM C# console app

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin, csom, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to a specific site's file directory in my org's SharePoint. I created an app on `https://OrgTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`. Then, I gave it FullControl permissions to the site on `https://OrgTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx` with the XML permissions as

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://OrgTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

I took the client ID and Secret from the app creation and used them in the my C# app's code (see below). I am able to connect to the site and pull information from the site, such as lists, and can see the the directory I am trying to load the file to in the List of lists, but get an Access Denied error when trying to upload the file. I can't seem to find any documentation online about why this may be and it has me thoroughly stumped. Let me know if I am missing something or if there are better alternatives to what I am trying to do as I am open to suggestions!

Code:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ProjectName
{
    class SharepointHelper
    {
        public static void LoadFilesToSharepoint()
        {
            string siteUrl = "https://OrgTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite";
            using (var cc = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, [My Client ID], [My Client Secret]))
            {
                cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title, p => p.Lists);
                cc.ExecuteQuery();
                Web web = cc.Web;

                string libraryName = "FileLocation";
                string filePath = "C:\\Folder\\testFileforSP.txt";
                List<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List> doclist = cc.Web.Lists.ToList();
                
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    FileCreationInformation flciNewFile = new FileCreationInformation();

                    flciNewFile.ContentStream = fs;
                    flciNewFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    flciNewFile.Overwrite = true;

                    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile);

                    cc.Load(uploadFile);
                    cc.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the Access Denied error up on the cc.ExecuteQuery() at the bottom.

I tried giving the app other permissions. I initially gave it Write permissions, then Manage, then Full Control as most examples I saw just gave the app full control so I thought this would help, but it did not. No matter what I did I got Access Denied or Unauthorized access (with lesser permissions).